# Ubuntu SDK, Ubuntu touch app: "Error: Error opening shm."

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch, development, ubuntu-sdk, qml

I am building an app for Ubuntu Touch. It works well on desktop, but when I try to open it on nexus it starts opening a splash screen but immediately crashes.
Here's the logs:

```
t_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4256]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5-32011 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4255]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
libust[4253/4255]: Error: Error opening shm /lttng-ust-wait-5 (in get_wait_shm() at lttng-ust-comm.c:886)
UbuntuWindow - regular geometry
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceResize(width=1200, height=1862)
UbuntuClipboard - Got invalid serialized mime data. Ignoring it.
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuClipboard - Got invalid serialized mime data. Ignoring it.
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=true)
UbuntuWindow::handleSurfaceFocusChange(focused=false)
```

Do you know what could that be?

(Nexus 7, Ubuntu Touch Utopic).

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but I can't comment yet.

Can you share any more code? Curious as to why there are so many focus changes. What image are you using on your Nex7?